# Me salta un error de BASH "Too many Arguments"

Tags: bash

El caso es, que en la lineas del While de Binario_a_octal y Binario_a_hexadecimal, me salta un error de Too many Arguments, llevo bastante con el error, y he deducido que el error podria estar en el binario_a_decimal concretamente en la parte de después del "case $binario".

Esta sería la función de binario a decimal:

```
binario_a_decimal() {

read -p "Introduce tu numero binario: " binario
case $binario in
    *[!01]*)
        echo "Error, introduce solo numeros binarios (0/1)"
        return
        ;;
    *)
        # En caso de que sea 0 y/o 1 no pasará nada y continuará con el codigo
        ;;
esac
decimal=0
i=0
    # Convertimos el binario a entero
while [ $binario -gt 0 ];
do
    digito=$((binario % 10))
    decimal=$((decimal + digito * 2**i))
    i=$((i + 1))
    binario=$((binario / 10))
done
echo $decimal
decimal="" 
}
```

Y estas serian las del Octal y Hexadecimal:

```
binario_a_octal() {
decimal=$(binario_a_decimal)
octal=""
while [ $decimal -gt 0 ];
do
    resto=$((decimal % 8))
    octal="$resto$octal"
    decimal=$((decimal / 8))
done
registro "binario octal" "$binario" "$octal"
echo $octal
}

binario_a_hexadecimal() {
decimal=$(binario_a_decimal)
hexadecimal=""
while [ $decimal -gt 0 ]; 
do
    resto=$((decimal % 16))
    case $resto in
        10) hexadecimal="A$hexadecimal" ;;
        11) hexadecimal="B$hexadecimal" ;;
        12) hexadecimal="C$hexadecimal" ;;
        13) hexadecimal="D$hexadecimal" ;;
        14) hexadecimal="E$hexadecimal" ;;
        15) hexadecimal="F$hexadecimal" ;;
        *) hexadecimal="$resto$hexadecimal" ;;
    esac
    decimal=$((decimal / 16))
done
registro "binario hexadecimal" "$binario" "$hexadecimal"
echo $hexadecimal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia, los errores de "too many arguments" suelen provenir de sentencias dentro de `[ expresion ]`, como `[ $decimal -gt 0 ]`.

Si es así, intenta poner entre comillas la variable *$decimal*, por ejemplo, `[ "$decimal" -gt 0 ]`. De esta manera, previenes los posibles splitting por la variable.